# How do I connect to a SQL Server DB to run some queries?

Tags: connection, sql-server

I have a **SQL Server DB** but have **no idea how to connect to it to run some queries**. I naively assumed that I'd be able to open up a DB in a similar fashion to Microsoft Access, but can't seem to do this. I have a copy of what I think is the primary DB file with .mdf suffix.

After a bit of searching, I've come across [Database .NET](http://fishcodelib.com/Database.htm) (suggested in a [SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/18527/less-daunting-front-end-for-sql-server#answer-18531)). Running this I'm trying to figure out *how to connect to the SQL Server DB* but have no clue how to go about this. Is there a specific syntax to use? Also, how to authenticate to a remote machine running a SQL Server DB?

Any ideas appreciated as I haven't got a clue!=

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quickest method would be to download SSMSE (SQL Server Management Studio Express).

It is free and works well.

[SSMSE for SQL 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en)

[SSMSE for SQL 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You generally can't simply connect to the database file; you need to connect to the database server that is using that database file, then connect to the database within the server. SQL Server Express is a free version, or you can use SQL Server proper if you have the right licenses